# Dos Batch - For Loop

Tags: batch-file

can anyone
tell me why in the example below the value of LIST is always blank
i would also like to only retrive the first 4 characters of %%i in variable LIST

```
cd E:\Department\Finance\edi\Japan_orders\
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b *.*') DO ( 

   copy %%i  E:\Department\Finance\Edi\commsfile.txt        

   set LIST=%%i
   echo %LIST%

   if %%i == FORD110509 CALL E:\Department\Finance\edi\EXTRACT.exe E:\Department\Finance\edi\COMMSFILE.TXT

)
pause
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need delayed expansion. Add the following at the start of your program:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and then use `!LIST!` instead of `%LIST%` inside of the loop.

For a thorough explanation please read `help set`.

Answer (score 2):

Bracketed command blocks are parsed entirely, and it is done *prior* to their execution. Your `%LIST%` expression, therefore, is expanded at the beginning, while the `LIST` variable is still empty. When the time comes to execute `echo %LIST%`, there's not `%LIST%` any more there, only the empty string (read: 'nothing') instead. It's just how it works (don't ask me why).

In such cases the delayed expansion mechanism is used, and Joey has already told you that you need to use a special syntax of `!LIST!` instead of `%LIST%`, which must first be enabled (typically, by the command `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`, which he has mentioned as well).

On your other point, you *can* extract a substring from a value, but the value must first be stored into a variable. Basically, the syntax for extracting substrings is one these:

```
%VARIABLE:~offset,charcount%
```

```
%VARIABLE:~offset%
```

That is, you are to specify the starting position (0-based) and, optionally, the number of characters to cut from the value. (If `quantity` is omitted then you are simply cutting the source string at the offset to the end.) You can read more about it by issuing `HELP SET` from the command line (wait, it's the same command that Joey has mentioned!).

One more thing: don't forget about the delayed expansion. You need to change the above `%` syntax to the `!` one. In your case the correct expression for retrieving the first 4 characters would be:

```
!LIST:~0,4!
```

You can use it directly or you could first store it back to `LIST` and then use simply `!LIST!` wherever you need the substring.